# Copy item with workflow with person type field, breaks in edit view

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a SharePoint 2013 workflow in SharePoint designer, when user submits the new item form, I create a new item in another list and copy all field values, workflow works fine but when I click on the item created in the second list to open and view item it works fine but when I edit Item, I get unexpected error.

I noticed that one of the fields (form has total 10 fields) in the form is of type person, If that field is filled, it works fine and I can open new item in edit mode but if person field in left bank, it breaks.

Is there any way to check if person column has value then copy the data otherwise just ignore it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a new workflow variable and set its value to `Current Item:Project Direct Report` and return field as `Login Name`.
2. Then add `IF condition` to check if the newly created variable is `empty or not`.
3. In `IF block`, set `Project Direct Report` in new list to workflow variable.
4. In `Else block`, igonre that field.

**Note**:

1. Ensure that you are having same schema for both the lists and you are not leaving any required fields blank.

Comment: worked, thank you for that. I am getting error sending email as well. I am getting this error Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to [mysiteurl]/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail

Comment: Please accept and upvote if this answer helped you. And kindly create new question for email error and add the complete error/screenshot in your question.

Comment: Have you got solution for sending email error?

Comment: no, still getting error, both it works fine in first list but second list throws error in sending email.

Comment: Please ask new question with complete details.... Screenshot of workflow and complete error you are getting after workflow suspends.